# sql expiry date use Trigger OR Schedule a Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this table :

[image]

Now, i like the way when the date expires. EndTime < GETDATE()

expire field is true.

What method should I use? use a trigger to true or a schedule job that run before run any query in this table?

Comment: What do you want to do when something expires?  Perhaps a flag in the data is sufficient.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's a education question
and I want a method to automatically change the expire field

Comment: There is no need to crooss-post questions: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73002/sql-expiry-date-use-trigger-or-schedule-a-job One question, in one site is enough.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted to another site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to put a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 
    DROP COLUMN expire 
GO

ALTER TABLE t1 
    ADD expire AS CONVERT(BIT, (CASE WHEN EndTime < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
GO
```

Comment: when expire true?
it automatically change ?

Comment: +1 . . . This is probably the best solution to the problem.

Comment: @amirabdollahi This column's value will be computed every time you try to `SELECT` it.